# Joining 2 dataframes in pandas with different column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I'm trying to join 2 dataframes in a kind of strange way and was wondering if anyone has any advice.

My first data frame looks like this, call it `df1`:

[image: teamStatsDF]

2nd one looks like, call it `df2`:

[image: teamGames]

I want my final output to merge each team's stats next to their respective names in the games dataframe. A brute force way I thought of doing this was to change the name of the `TEAM` column in `df1` to `Home`, join it on that. Then, change the `TEAM` column to `Visitor` and join it on that too but I feel their should be an easier way. Can anyone give me advice on this, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide samples of your data as text rather than images. `df.head().to_dict()` for each dataframe should suffice. This way we can easily test and propose solutions.

Comment: In addition, please read how to produce a [mcve].  It's a help us help you scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left_on` and `right_on` parameters from `pd.merge`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['a','b','c','d','e','b'], 'val2': [31,43,23,54,65,23]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': ['a','b','c'], 'val1': [11,22,33]})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col2', how='left')
print(df3)

  col1 val2 col2 val1
0   a   31   a   11.0
1   b   43   b   22.0
2   c   23   c   33.0
3   d   54  NaN  NaN
4   e   65  NaN  NaN
5   b   23   b   22.0
```